# Boomla: how to sort all files in parent alphabetically

Tags: boomla

I have uploaded loads of files in a gallery and I want them to show up in file name order. Sorting manually is a pain, how can I automate it?

Answer (score 0):

You can run javascript code in an `sjs-3` interpreter. There is a [js-console](http://js-console.app.boomla.com) for it that can access your website directly so that you don't need to create an app and run it.

Use this code snippet to sort the children of in `//example.com`:

```
var sortFilesIn = function(path) {
    compare = function(a,b) {
        if (a.name() < b.name()) {
            return -1
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    }

    parent = f.select(path)
    files = []
    parent.children().each(function(fi) {
        files.push(fi)
    })

    files.sort(compare)

    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        var fi = files[i]
        fi.move(os.APPEND, parent, "", 0)
    }
}

sortFilesIn('//example.com')

response.body('ok')
```